# Padrão Singleton e Prototype

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde me deparei com a seguinte situação:
Existem duas famílias de algoritmos que usam um determinado objeto de formas distintas: a primeira apenas ler os dados e faz um processamento, já a segunda modifica o objeto.

O meu problema é: esse objeto que essas famílias é extremamente grande e gasta muito tempo pra ler as informações em memória, logo ficar criando esse objeto toda hora será um problema.

Eu sei que pra a família que apenas ler os dados, o singleton poderia ser uma solução e já para a família que modifica poderia usar o prototype.

Eu queria saber se é possível combinar esses dois padrões, pois estou usando uma fábrica abstrata e não tenho certeza se da pra determinar qual usar em tempo de execução (para cada uma das famílias).

Comment: Você sabe qual "modelo" cada trecho de código usaria? Se sim, pode ter objetos diferentes, cada um usando um padrão específico.

Comment: Sim, eu sei.  Minha dúvida é se posso especificar isso no método fábrica de cada uma das famílias?

Comment: Nesta frase "O meu problema é: esse objeto que essas famílias é extremamente e gasta muito tempo" parece que ficaram a faltar algumas palavras. Quanto à pergunta o ideal é adicionar código para exemplificar o seu problema. Se for com uma versão simplificada do seu codigo real ainda melhor